# Ajax call throwing an error but I see response on Fiddler

Tags: ajax, jquery

My page using ajax call to get an username.
I see response in Fiddler but it still throws an error.

Here is my code:

```
$.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "Selection.aspx/GetUser",
               data: "{}",
               contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
               dataType: "json",
               success: function (response) {
                   var username = response.d;
                   if (username.indexOf("ERROR") > 0) {
                       jAlert(username);
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       if( username!= "" ) 
                       {
                           $("#MainContent_lblUser").text(username);
                       }
                   }
                },
               error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                   if (xhr.responseText != "") {
                       var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                       jAlert(err.Message);
                   } else
                       jAlert('Unable to get an User', 'Ajax Error', null);
               }
           });
```

I always see an alert "Unable to get User".
In Fiddler I see {"d":"Domain\crm.admin"}

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well `{"d":"Domain\crm.admin"}` isn't valid json, escape the \   -> `{"d":"Domain\\crm.admin"}`

Comment: I tried that no luck.

Comment: show ur Selection.aspx/GetUser fuction.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are really returning a JSON object.  If you aren't sure then edit the dataType specification and add some extra code in your success callback; for example:

```
$.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "Selection.aspx/GetUser",
               data: "{}",
               contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",                  
               success: function (response) {
                   newResponse = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
                   var username = newResponse.d;
                   if (username.indexOf("ERROR") > 0) {
                       jAlert(username);
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       if( username!= "" ) 
                       {
                           $("#MainContent_lblUser").text(username);
                       }
                   }
                },
               error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                   if (xhr.responseText != "") {
                       var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                       jAlert(err.Message);
                   } else
                       jAlert('Unable to get an User', 'Ajax Error', null);
               }
           });
```

I hope this helps